# How to use the digest library on a column in r

Tags: r, loops, hash, sha256

I get an error using this:

```
for (i in nrow(df$uuid)){df$uuid[[,i]] <- (digest(df$uuid[i,], algo=c("sha256")))}
```

> Error in 1:nrow(s12$uuid) : argument of length 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A vector doesn't have an `nrow` value, only a `length` value:

```r
x <- 1:10
nrow(x)
#> NULL
```

This includes vectors housed in data frames:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
nrow(df$x)
#> NULL
```

Whereas, the data frame itself has an `nrow` (the number of rows) **and** a `length` (the number of columns):

```r
nrow(df)
#> [1] 10
length(df)
#> [1] 1
```

You need to be careful when iterating that you are iterating along the correct "dimension" of the correct entity. In your case this means you should either give the `for` loop the `nrow` of your data frame *or* the `length` of one of its vectors (both will be the same), but *not* the `nrow` of one of its vectors, since that will be `NULL`.

It's not clear what `len` does in your example - is that a function you have pre-defined? Is it just a synonym for `nrow`?

The structure of your data isn't shown in your question, so let's make a really simple example. We will have a `uuid` column for "data" and create an empty column for the hash.

```r
df <- data.frame(uuid = c("hello", "world"))
df$hash <- character(nrow(df))
```

To populate the hash column, we do:

```r
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) df$hash[i] <- digest::digest(df$uuid[i], algo = "sha256")
```

Which results in:

```r
#>   uuid                                                              hash
#> 1 hello 5d3c36bc8d42c8b679ba1ef4ef3c2bf7674fc42ae33a474b9ac1a032a24b9b1d
#> 2 world c2269227fa81bc9731bedddfe41594c00e3be9327e33339053ebc395adb4fa76
```

Comment: I meant nrow, and I corrected it now, I tried your code and got the error: 
Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: @VictorNielsen that's probably because your data frame is not actually called `df`

Comment: @VictorNielsen if you copy and paste my code, including my data frame you will see it works fine if you actually have a dataframe csaled `df`